# icCube Schema Refresh Time - last "real" data load

Tags: mdx, olap, iccube

The SchemaRefreshTime in icCube shows the last date/time a schema has been refreshed, including a load from an offline cube.

This could give the strange situation that you "restore" an old situation (using an offline cube) but the end-users will see in the last refresh time the date the cube was loaded. Not desirable. I would like them to show that the data in fact is old (namely the date/time of the data in the offline cube).

Is it possible to show the time the data was actually refreshed with data from a "real" source, and when you load data from an offline cube, show the data the contents of the offline cube was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this information is not available in the snapshot. You can follow this issue ([www](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-180)).